# f, h cont diff. Find necessary and sufficient conditions for these functions to be first-order approximations of each other at the point (0,0).

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

Suppose that the functions $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and $h: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ are continuously differentiable. Find necessary and sufficient conditions for these functions to be first-order approximations of each other at the point (0,0).

Comment: Do you know the *definition* of "first-order approximation"?

Comment: Yes, from the theorem: let O be an open subset of R^n and suppose that the function f: O -> R is cont diff. Let x be a point in O. Then lim as h -> 0 (f(x+h)-[f(x)+<grad*f(x),h>])/ ||h|| = 0

Comment: Then, start calculating the gradients of the functions.

Comment: Ok, so for f, we get that f' = df/dx(0,0)+df/dy(0,0) and similarly for h' = dh/dx(0,0)+dh/dy(0,0). Should I put these in the equation and simply solve to see when they are equivalent?

Comment: Gradient is a *vector*...

Comment: I think I need a little more guidance to understand because I am still confused. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_approximation#First-order.

First-order approximation means coincidence of functions and first derivatives in the point, so
$$f(0,0) = h(0,0)$$
$$\cdots = Df(0,0) = Dh(0,0) = \cdots$$
where you can write $Df(0,0)$, $Dh(0,0)$ using partial derivatives...